Commutation relation between charge number and phase in superconductors
Consider an isolated Cooper pair box.
The charge number operator is
$$\hat{n} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} n |n\rangle \langle n|$$
where $|n \rangle$ is the state in which $n$ Cooper pairs have passed from one side of the junction to the other due to the tunneling effect.
Clearly, it results that
$$\hat{n} |n \rangle = n |n \rangle$$
Define the phase state
$$| \varphi \rangle = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{in\varphi} |n\rangle$$
It can be seen that
$$| \varphi + 2\pi \rangle = | \varphi \rangle $$
which means that $\varphi$ varies in a compact segment of length $2\pi$.
Define also the operator
$$e^{i\hat{\varphi}} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\varphi \, e^{i\varphi} |\varphi \rangle \langle \varphi|$$
Doing the math, I find that
$$[e^{i\hat{\varphi}},\hat n] = e^{i\hat{\varphi}}$$
Now, assuming the existence of the operator $\hat{\varphi}$ itself, I find that the last commutation relation is equivalent to the following:
$$[\hat{\varphi},\hat n]=-i$$
However, I usually find this commutation relation with a different sign. Is there an error in the derivation?

Sign is really a matter of convention - changing the sign in the exponent would probably change that of the commutation relation. Often this is simply postulated without elaborate reasoning, as for any two conjugate variables: $[x,p]=i\hbar$ etc.

$|\varphi\rangle$ does not exist since the series which defines it  always diverges in the Hilbert space. How do you intepret $|\varphi\rangle$? (Ex falso quodlibet)

I was following Langford's lecture notes and Girvin's lecture notes on circuit QED (they can be easily found in the web). Both define phase states in this way (but they are introductory notes and I think they don't aspire to great mathematical rigor)
